# How to response http request from eventbus consumer

Tags: java, vert.x

Changed:
How to response http request from socket.
Web code:

```
public void start() {
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
    router.route("/api/getdata").handler(this::getData);
    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8080);
}

private void getData(RoutingContext routingContext) {
    vertx.eventBus().send(ServerVerticle.ADDRESS, pricemessage, reply -> {

    });
}
```

Socket code:

```
public void start() {
    final EventBus eb = vertx.eventBus();
    NetClient netClient = vertx.createNetClient();
    if (ar.succeeded()) {
        socket.handler(this::onDataReceived);
        eb.consumer(ServerVerticle.ADDRESS, message -> {
            socket.write(buffer);   // request from the getData method
            message.reply(data);// no data here, it's in the handler
        }
    }
}

private void onDataReceived(Buffer buffer) {
    // buffer changed to JsonObject here
    vertx.eventBus().send("some address here", jsonObject);
}
```

The socket handler has no return value. Just a eventbus send.
And I don't know how to response this jsonObject to the http request.

========================================================================

Old question, maybe not clear.
I have a vertex that handles the socket write and response.

```
public void start() {   // 1
    NetClient netClient = vertx.createNetClient();
    netClient.connect(port, host, ar -> {
        socket = ar.result(); // NetSocket
        socket.handler(this::doSocketHandleMethod);
        socket.write(BYTEBUFFER);// buffer here
    })
}

private void doSocketHandleMethod(Buffer buffer){ // socket handler 
    // process data here and send
    vertx.eventBus().send(ADDRESS, data here);
}
```

I use the below code to fetch the response from the http request.

```
public void start() {
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
    router.route(API_GET).handler(this::getData);

    vertx.eventBus().consumer(ADDRESSHERE, msg -> {
        // get data from the socket send.    2
    });
         vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8080, result -> {

        });
}

private void getData(RoutingContext routingContext) {
    vertx.eventBus().send(ADDRESS, message); // send message to the top // 1 verticle

// 3 
}
```

The question is that the second code mention above gets the the data, but not sure how to fetch the response from the http reqest 3.

Answer (score 1):

The (*HttpServerRequest*) is passed to the route (`requestHandler(router::accept)`) and is contained in the *RoutingContext*. *"As HTTP requests are received by the server, instances of [...].HttpServerRequest will be created and passed to this handler."* - JavaDoc

So, if the data arrives at 2 and you want to do a response to a *HttpServerRequest* (as a third step), you can use `routingContext.response()` in the `getData()` method, to get a *HttpServerResponse*.

---

If you want to handle a http server request, by sending a message to a consumer that is getting some data from a socket and want to send this result as a reply to the specific http server request, then you may do something like this:

```
// Send a message and get the response via handler
private void getData(RoutingContext routingContext) {
vertx.eventBus().send(ADDRESS, message, handler -> {
  if(handler.succeded()) {
    routingContext.response().end(handler.result());
  }
  else {
    // error
  }
});
}

// To reply to a message do
vertx.eventBus().consumer(ADDRESSHERE, msg -> {
    // get data from the socket send.    2
  msg.reply(data); // you can only do a reply once. Put data into reply
});
```

---

As far as I know, the event bus only knows "send and reply" and not a concept like a socket. It looks like you want to send data everytime new data is available through the socket.

You can write something to a httpResponse mutliple times, so you need to **save a reference to the response object**.

But I do not know, if that is such a good idea. I would recommend to encapsulate the socket-get-data process. The "socket" verticle only answers once, with the whole buffer it got. Here are two examples on what I mean.

```
// open socket
vertx.eventBus().consumer("ADRRESS", message -> {
  // execute this on worker thread to not block the event bus thread
  vertx.executeBlocking(future -> {
    Buffer buffer = Buffer.buffer();
    socket.handler(buff -> buffer.appendBuffer(buff)) // read data
    .endHandler(endHandler -> {
      // no more data to read
      socket.pause();
      future.complete(buffer);
    })
    .resume() // socket was paused, now read the data
    .exceptionHandler(err -> future.fail(err)); // handle exception
  }, result -> {
    if(result.succeeded()) {
      message.reply(result.result()); // reply with the buffer content
    }
    else {
      message.reply(result.cause()); // may want to send error later
    }
  });
});

// connect and get a new socket every time
vertx.eventBus().consumer("ADRRESS", message -> {
  // execute this on worker thread to not block the event bus thread
  vertx.executeBlocking(future -> {
    netClient.connect(1, "", netSocketHandler -> {
      if(netSocketHandler.succeeded()) {
        Buffer buffer = Buffer.buffer();
        netSocketHandler.result().handler(buff -> buffer.appendBuffer(buff)) // read data
        .endHandler(endHandler -> {
          // no more data to read
          future.complete(buffer);
          netSocketHandler.result().close(); // close the NetSocket once finished
        })
        .exceptionHandler(err -> {
          netSocketHandler.result().close();
          future.fail(err);
        }); // handle exceptions
      }
      else {
        future.fail(netSocketHandler.cause());
      }
    });
  }, result -> {
    if(result.succeeded()) {
      message.reply(result.result()); // reply with the buffer content
    }
    else {
      message.reply(result.cause()); // may want to send error later
    }
  });
});
```

If this realy does not help you, I'm sorry, and maybe this is not the concept you are looking for.

Comment: But get a HttpServerResponse, then the data are in vertx.eventBus().consumer.
The main point of this question is: How to response http request from eventbus consumer.

Comment: @lanjingyu, you're not supposed to do that. The whole idea of consumers is that they're not aware of how their response will be used.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is  when get data from the socket , there is no return value. The socket use a handler too and that handler still use a eventbus.send.  
Code here:  socket.write(buffer);
socket.handler(this::receiveData);

Comment: `vertx.eventBus().consumer(ADDRESSHERE, msg -> {
  socket.write(buffer); // no data here
  msg.reply(data); 
});
socket.handler(this::recieveData);
recieveData function {
     eventbus.send();  
}
`

Comment: So I think maybe need a bridge or sockjs thing. I'm trying.